# Navigate Url in Hyperlink is not redirect my page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `HyperLink` where I use `NavigateUrl` Attribute and give the URL properly but this link in not redirect the target page. Can you help but when I redirect the URL using code behind then its working properly. I have also mention the code which I use in Code behind, but I don't want to put my code on code behind. Can you help me what is wrong here.

```
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkAddUser" runat="server" onclick="return GB_show('Add Hiring Manager', this.href, 500, 650)"
            ImageUrl="~/Images/Resources/thumb/add.png" ToolTip="Add Hiring Manager" Text="Add Hiring Manager"></asp:HyperLink>
        **<%--NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Recruiter/AddUser.aspx?UserId=0" + "&ProfileId=" + hdnClientId.Value  + "&UserTypeId=8"  %>'--%>**

        string hlnkAddUserurl = string.Format("~/Recruiter/AddUser.aspx?UserId=0" + "ProfileId=" + hdnClientId.Value + "UserTypeId=8");
        hlnkAddUser.NavigateUrl = hlnkAddUserurl;
```

Comment: onclick="return GB_show('Add Hiring Manager', this.href, 500, 650)" instead OnmClinetClick="return GB_show('Add Hiring Manager', this.href, 500, 650)"

Comment: check the html source when the page is rendered if it is picking the value of hdnClientId.Value and if the url is being formed correctly

Comment: thanks Adnan@, its picking the value properly..

Comment: Please accept the answers given to your (other) questions because people would resist to help you or in other way it may help someone considering that other people have same problem as you had faced..

Answer (score 0):

If your onclick function will return 'false' then default browser action (redirect to page provided in href attribute) will not take place.

Make sure GB_Show does not return false.

Comment: hey ITmeze, GB_Show is working fine bcoz its redirect the page but dont display the page contain or controls...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the databinding server tags such as `<%# #>`, `<%: %:>` and `<%= %>` which will work good enough if they are inside the databinding controls such as `GridView`, `Repeater`, and `FormView`, etc.

I suggest you go with the server-side code only because even if you put the code on `.aspx` or `.aspx.cs` it will of course execute on the server-side and send response to the client-side aka User or Browser.

So doing code as below is not wrong in such case.

```
string hlnkAddUserurl = string.Format("~/Recruiter/AddUser.aspx?UserId={0}&ProfileId={1}&UserTypeId={2}", 0, hdnClientId.Value, 8);
hlnkAddUser.NavigateUrl = hlnkAddUserurl;
```

*Note: The corrected `string.Format` usage shown in the code and query string corrections to add `&` in between the key-value pairs*

**Reference links**

1. [SO - Dynamically set hyperlink control's navigateurl property inline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3594162/468718)
2. [SO - Asp.net HyperLink dynamic creation of NavigateUrl path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11935383/468718)
3. [MSDN - String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: @Sandeep Any inputs ? My answer helps you or need more help?

Comment: Thanks Harsh Baid, but i already using this code, i want to place my URL in .aspx page